# Epaminondas puzzle

Tags: puzzles, epaminondas

In this [description of Epaminondas with puzzles at the bottom](http://www.logicmazes.com/games/epam/index.html), what is the solution to the first puzzle?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The solution is for white to move their row of 3 one space forward. There are a bunch of possible moves for black but white can guarantee a win from all of them.

[image]

## If black moves away from their back line:

If black moves their leftmost piece away from the line, then red pushes forward. Black is forced to use their remaining 2 to capture red, who captures again. Black can't capture the remaining piece.

[image]

This is similar to the situation with the rightmost piece:

[image]

If black moves the middle piece away, then they will have to reform the broken 2 in order to defend the back line. Red aims a phalanx there:

[image]

If black moves the middle piece to the side to avoid this diagonal phalanx, red goes too far away on the other side:

[image]

## If black stays on the back line

If black is staying on the back line, then their first move cannot be to the left. Any distance to the left allows red to take the first capture and keep pushing to win. Thus black moves right. If black moves more than one space to the right, then they're too far away to defend from the single piece moving in. If black moves one space to the right, red forces the black row to capture their piece, lining up the black phalanx to be split in half:

[image]

Comment: That said, this question is probably more suited to the [Puzzling Stack Exchange](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com).

Comment: And probably this answer is oversimplified - I've been playing with having black make the best defensive move each time and it's tough!

Comment: You cannot choose how black moves; you should show that it cannot play in any way so as to prevent the win by white. Also to win white only needs one of its pieces on black's back rank (since black is nowhere near white's back rank).

Comment: @hkBst Right! I think I've got it, just working through the possibilities.

Comment: @hkBst Okay, I worked it out over lunch with some board game parts :P I'll write it up now!

Comment: From [the help](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "Questions about Go problems or Chess problems are fine, even if they are static puzzles, since they are related to a dynamic game." Can be extended to Epaminondas so this question is certainly on-topic here (as well as on Puzzling).

Comment: NOPE I GOT IT WRONG AGAIN AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARGH

Comment: Okay, I've actually got it! Finishing this up.

Comment: I don't think these 'forced captures' are mandatory, sorry.

Comment: If the middle black piece moves out of line, red can immediately move forwards for a win, because black cannot recapture.

Comment: @hkBst Right you are, but I this way gets a win in exactly three moves :D

Comment: @freekvd Every move I label as "forced" is one which, if black _doesn't_ take that move, black loses immediately.